# what does & mean in mathematica? what's its usage?

Tags: scripting

when I type 1 & 8
I get this: 8 (1 &)
why do I get this output?
and when I type f[#,a]&x, the output is  x (f[#1,a]&)

Comment: see [Function (&)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html)

Comment: See [What the @#%^&*?! do all those funny signs mean?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/5478) in linked topic. Also, you can always hit F1.